# Python Parimiko not loading progress and data into textbox

Tags: python, tkinter, paramiko

I am currently building script to automate backup process. The script works fine dumping output from shell into textbox up until step 6 where the back procedure actually occurs. In the shell it uses "....." as a progress bar but when script completes it does not show its output in textbox but only in the console when printed. I want this output to show in textbox. Also is there anyway I can keep looping to check for such keywords to detect if command is completing instead of guessing by using sleep? Thanks

```
import datetime, time
from time import sleep
from Tkinter import *
import paramiko
def cms():
    canvas = Canvas(page3, relief = FLAT, background = "#D2D2D2", width = 694, height = 120)
    canvas.pack()  
    txtOutput = Text(canvas, wrap = NONE, height =14, width = 86, borderwidth=2)
    txtOutput.pack()
    try:
       ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
       ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
       ssh.connect(server, port=22, username='user', password='pass')
       channel = ssh.invoke_shell()

   except paramiko.AuthenticationException:
       print("Authentication failed, please verify your credentials: %s")
   except paramiko.SSHException as sshException:
       print("Unable to establish SSH connection: %s" % sshException)
   except paramiko.BadHostKeyException as badHostKeyException:
       print("Unable to verify server's host key: %s" % badHostKeyException)
   except Exception as e:
       print(e.args)
   command = ['command1','command2','command3','command4','command5','command6','command7']

   i=0
   for commands in command: 
       if i == 6:
           channel.send(command[i]+'\n')
           print("**Backup started**")
           while not channel.recv_ready():#Wait for the server to read and respond
               time.sleep(10)
           time.sleep(240)
           print("**Backup completed**")
           output2 = channel.recv(9999)    
           print(output2.decode('utf-8'))  
           txtOutput.insert(END,output2)
           txtOutput.update_idletasks()#update the output one line at time

       else:
            channel.send(command[i] + '\n') 
            print(commands + "command has started**")#display command and press enter
            while not channel.recv_ready(): #Wait for the server to read and respond
               time.sleep(3)
            time.sleep(1)
            print(commands + "command has ended**")#wait enough for writing to (hopefully) be finished
            output = channel.recv(9999) #read in
            print(output.decode('utf-8'))  
            txtOutput.insert(END,output.decode('utf-8'))
            txtOutput.update_idletasks()#update the output one line at time


    i+=1

print("Completed we will now close connection!!")
ssh.close()
```

Comment: Please transform your code into a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), it will be easier to help you.

Comment: No problem, i updated code and explantion

Comment: The import statements and the definition of some objects like `channel` or `txtOutput` are still missing. The idea of a MCVE is that anyone can just copy/paste your code snippet and run it to see what's happening.

Comment: Using sleep along with tkinter is usually not a good idea because it suspends tkinter's mainloop and therefore freezes the GUI. Tkinter provides the `.after` method to schedule a function call.

Comment: Yes but how would i go about using this? will after not cause to call backup multiple times? i only want to call it once and let it loop along commands?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure this will solve the issue but this is how I would replace the use of `sleep` by `after`. I have split the for loop into several functions. `send_cmd(i)` start the execution of command i and launch `check` which periodically check whether the server is ready and then schedule the output fetching.

```
def cms():
    canvas = Canvas(page3, relief = FLAT, background = "#D2D2D2", width = 694, height = 120)
    canvas.pack()
    txtOutput = Text(canvas, wrap = NONE, height =14, width = 86, borderwidth=2)
    txtOutput.pack()
    try:
        ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
        ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
        ssh.connect(server, port=22, username='user', password='pass')
        channel = ssh.invoke_shell()

    except paramiko.AuthenticationException:
        print("Authentication failed, please verify your credentials: %s")
    except paramiko.SSHException as sshException:
        print("Unable to establish SSH connection: %s" % sshException)
    except paramiko.BadHostKeyException as badHostKeyException:
        print("Unable to verify server's host key: %s" % badHostKeyException)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e.args)

    command = ['command1','command2','command3','command4','command5','command6','command7','command8']

    def send_cmd(i):
        if i == 6:
            print("**Backup started**")
            channel.send(command[i]+'\n')
            check2()
        else:
            print(command[i] + "command has started**")
            channel.send(command[i]+'\n')
            check1(i)


    def check1(i):
        if not channel.recv_ready():
            txtOutput.after(3000, check1, i)  # wait 3s and re-check
        else:  # server is ready, wait for execution to end and fetch output
            txtOutput.after(1000, get, command[i] + "command has ended**", i)


    def check2():
        if not channel.recv_ready():
            txtOutput.after(10000, check2)  # wait 3s and re-check
        else:  # server is ready, wait for execution to end and fetch output
            txtOutput.after(240000, get, "**Backup completed**", 6)

    def get(msg, i):
        print(msg)
        output = channel.recv(9999) #read in
        print(output.decode('utf-8'))
        txtOutput.insert(END, output.decode('utf-8'))
        if i < len(command) - 1:
            send_cmd(i + 1)  # launch next command
        else:  # no more command to launch, close ssh
            ssh.close()

    send_cmd(0)
```

Comment: I will have a go at running this, so for me to run this using button it should go something like this?

Comment: myServer.configure(width = 10,height = 2,  relief = RAISED, bd=2,bg = '#D2D2D2',command=lambda:cms())

Comment: @MarkKin You don't need the `lambda` since `cms` doesn't take any argument. I have edited my answer because I had forgotten to actually launch the first function.

Comment: Thanks, and yes just noticed that, where do i implement ssh.close() after script is complete?

Comment: @MarkKin I have added it in the `get` function

Comment: @MarkKin I am not sure I understand. From your code `i == 6` corresponds to `'command7'` so I thought that `command7` was the backup. If instead `'command6'` is the backup then you will need to change the if statements in my code (in both `send_cmd` and `get`).

Comment: Sorry my bad, you are correct , however i left out an additional 'command8' which is a validate command which should use check1 , how do i modify the if to suit this so after the backup it performs one last short command

Comment: @MarkKin I have edited the code: test for `i == 6` instead of `i < 6` in `send_cmd`.

Comment: @j-4321 Yes, still yet to test, is there anyway of the script to keep checking to detect whether the string "finished" has been output? like to keep looping to check instead of guessing and waiting 3 minutes. You could use something like this but not sure how to implement it to keep checking and to break out if its there?

Comment: `a = ['backup', 'finished']'
str = output

if all(x in str for x in a):

    print "im here"

else:
    print "im not"`